# How do I get javascript's Date.parse() in .Net?

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net, json, datetime

I'm using .NET to generate a JSON file that has many `Date`s in it.

For compression, I want to store them as milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 and not strings, then convert them to Javascript Dates.  But .Net's idea of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 don't match Javascript:

Javascript:

```
Date.parse("2012-05-15T13:57:57.0000000+00:00")
1337090277000
```

VB.Net:

```
Date.Parse("2012-05-15T13:57:57.0000000+00:00").Subtract(New Date(1970,1,1)).TotalMilliseconds
1337101077000.0
```

The difference is `10800` seconds.  The difference at 1970-01-01 is 0 and changes over time.

Is there a way to compute Javascript's idea of milliseconds-since-epoch from within .Net?

Comment: The difference is 3 hours exactly. Perhaps the original time was from a different time zone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing apples to oranges.

This is exactly what you would get in javascript as well when in UTC+3 (Israel):

```
Date.parse("2012-05-15T13:57:57.0000000+00:00") - new Date(1970,1,1)
//1334419077000
```

This is because when you do `new Date` in javascript, that's according to the machine's timezone. It looks like it's the same for vb.net.

---

You would get the correct number in javascript with:

```
Date.parse("2012-05-15T13:57:57.0000000+00:00") - Date.UTC(1970,1,1)
//1334411877000
```

In VB.net

```
    Dim a As Date
    a = Date.Parse("2012-05-15T13:57:57.0000000+00:00").ToUniversalTime()
    Dim b As Date
    b = New Date(1970, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
    a.Subtract(b).TotalMilliseconds
    '1334411877000 Same as javascript
    'Note that in javascript, month as 1 is same as 2 in VB.net because months start at 0 in javascript
```

Comment: Oy, of course!  Replacing Date with DateTimeOffset solves my problem unambigously.  I don't like giving a timezone to the Date constructor.

Comment: @Eyal Why would you want to do that? It's unnecessary moving part. UTC is always the same.

Comment: The output of your final answer is not 1334411877000.0, it's 1337101077000.  ?Date.Parse("1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00").Subtract(New Date(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds, by the way, is 72000000.  VB.Net's Date.Parse() is ignoring the timezone.

Comment: @Eyal can you try like this: `DateTime.ParseExact( "2012-05-15T13:57:57.0000000+00:00", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ",System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: @Eyal or `Date.Parse("2012-05-15T13:57:57.0000000+00:00").TotalMilliSeconds - New Date(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).TotalMilliseconds`

Comment: Come on, man, you're not even testing your code!  The last one doesn't compile (no TotalMilliseconds member on Date) and the one before throws an exception (the timezone is format zzz)!  I'll use DateTimeOffset and be done with it.

Comment: @Eyal Sorry I have never wrote VB/VB.NET in my life. I installed visual studio and managed to get it to work. See my edit. My personal opinion so far is that VB.NET makes it really hard to work with UTC dates, there must be some config to make it easier. It basically never makes sense to work with other timezones until visual display.